# NumberPicker does not appears correctly on an Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-number-picker

I'm having some issues with the number picker on an Android 4.4.2. Sometimes it shows only a blue bar, sometimes nothing. See pictures below:

[image]

[image]

I've tested on an emulator with Android 4.4.2, its works perfectly.
It should appears as follows:

[image]

An idea ?

Comment: Did you rotate your device? Also, are you sure your device is 4.4.2? The emulator screenshot shows the default  AlertDialog buttons, while your device screenshot doesn't.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've edited the post. Actually you cannot rotate the App... It's blocked. A user transferred me the pictures and told me that he uses a Galaxy S5 mini with Android 4.4.2. I've verified his specifications...